# c# Linq Take 5 Object for each Group

Tags: c#, linq

I try Get 5 Object in each group to display.
I tried code like this:

```
var BBS = (from bb in db.Object
           where SubjectList.Contain(bb.Type)
           select new ObjectModel {
               Subject = bb.Subject,
               CDate = bb.CDate
           }).GroupBy(a => a.BBSTypeSubject).Take(5);
```

but it doesn't work.
and then I try it by using Foreach

Comment: could it be as simple as take(5) should be Take(5) ?

Comment: `contain` ,  `take`? formatting? . how about taking some time and asking a good question?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work".  Are you getting an error?  Is there an exception being thrown? Please clarify.

Comment: c# is case sensitive!

Comment: I apologize ask ambiguous question. 
"Doesn't working" is mean that result is not quite right. 
I took 5 groups and several objects in each groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, realize that C# is case sensitive, so you ***need*** to spell function names like `Take` and `Contains` correctly. But you can solve this problem fairly easily by just using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx) of `GroupBy` instead.

```
var BBS = (from bb in db.Object
           where SubjectList.Contains(bb.Type)
           select new ObjectModel {
               Subject = bb.Subject,
               CDate = bb.CDate
           }).GroupBy(a => a.BBSTypeSubject, (k, g) => g.Take(5));
```

The second parameter allows you to specify what result object will be returned for each group. In this case, I simply take the first 5 items from the group and return those instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you select new ObjectModel, there's no property called BBSTypeSubject. You need to include that. So it should be

```
select new ObjectModel {
 Subject = bb.Subject, 
 CDate = bb.CDate,
 BBSTypeSubject= ???
}
```

Comment: It's my fault, when I type this. I assigned value in my code.